# How can i search an array elements into a textfield ,its textfield will be suggest when each word pressed on textField from the array only?

Tags: ios, arrays

How can i search an array elements into a textfield ,its textfield will be suggest  when each word pressed on textField from the array only?Is it possible? with swift 3.0 and xcode 8.

Comment: subject and question both are same gr8. Please make your question more clear .

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this when you type you will have a filtered array 
     just connect this action method to textfield didchangeevent

```
  @IBAction func textFiledDidChange(_ textFiled : UITextField){
         var arr : [String] = ["a","ab","abc"]
         ///replace ("ab") with textfield.text!
         let filteredArr = arr.filter({$0.contains("ab")})
         print(filteredArr)
         /// filteredArr will contain now ["ab","abc"]    
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help,

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let array = ["g","d","s","a"]
        if array.contains(string) {
            // Typed character is in the array
        } else {
            // Typed character is not in the array
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Thank you .it was workable but i actually need when i press a word like Au,if my array contains "Austin" it will search when we search in the google like suggestive....